# Need to understand how this circuit works

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, ac, dc

I am a complete beginner in the field of electrical engineering. Recently, I came across the circuit displayed below and have successfully tested it using both software and hardware simulations. The circuit functions very properly, allowing me to utilize it without considering how it works. However, my curiosity has been piqued, particularly concerning the role of the three diodes: D1, D2, and D3. These diodes play a pivotal role in transforming 220VAC into 15VDC, a phenomenon I really want to comprehend.

Additionally, I really want to understand the limitations of this circuit, particularly why it cannot provide a higher current output, such as 1A. Although the current it currently generates suffices for my needs, I am intrigued by the reasons behind this restriction. The output displayed by the circuit matches the sharp 5V reading observed on my multimeter.

Any insights into these aspects would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Circuit]
[image: Circuit Output]

Comment: Google "capacitive dropper" and "transformerless power supply" for details. Basically, C1 is used to drop some voltage across, so the voltage before rectifier drops to some manageable levels. `why it cannot provide a higher current output` because you'll need larger values for C1. As it gets larger it gets physically bigger. One problem with this circuit is that it has direct connection with mains so there's a high risk of electric shock.

Comment: Beware.  This circuit can be dangerous, lethal voltages and a fire risk (especially for beginners that may not yet appreciate the issues).  Please do study the "Capacitive Dropper" (as suggested by @RohatKılıç ), and learn of all of the short-comings and dangers of this circuit.  Give mains inputs the respect it deserves, add over current protection, and use properly rated components (i.e. C1 capacitor).

Comment: What relevance has the channel A plot in the question?

Comment: With this circuit, if you want 1A out, then you must have 1A in. So. 220W in for 5W out - 215W gets wasted as heat. C1 will be fairly large and D3 will be larger and get hotter. Basically this circuit doesn’t scale well so you usually only see it in low power applications. For higher currents, there are smaller, cheaper and more efficient solutions. These days it tends to be some form of switching regulator or the classic iron transformer.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit employs a few classical blocks in electronics.

**Disclaimer: this is a potentially dangerous circuit, in a real application, as already annotated in the comments.**
Given the fact you aren't aware of the parts that build it, I warmly discourage you from using it; you should choose a galvanically isolated solution!

That said, basically C1 and D1 is a [clamper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamper_(electronics)), D2 and C2 a [rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier) and filter.

D3 is a shunt pre-regulator, which limits maximum voltage to U1 input; what's important here is the current limitation needed for D3, which is achieved both with C1 [reactance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance) and R2 (which limits [inrush current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current) at turn-on).

In short, the limit imposed to D3 current is also the limit inherited by the successive regulator: this is a very inefficient design, designed just for simplicity, where the load current is low and there's **no galvanic isolation** needed.

R1 discharges any residual charge in C1 when the circuit is powered off (a safety measure).

C2-R3-C3 are arranged as a [pi filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_filter#T_and_%CF%80_filters), to reduce some more of the inefficiency of the [half-wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Half-wave_rectification) rectifier.

Comment: I am eager to understand the potential risks associated with this circuit to ensure my safety. I have refrained from touching any part of it while the AC power is active. Rigorous testing on a breadboard was conducted, and components were handled only when the power was off. The small capacitance of C1 (470nF) ensures rapid discharge through R1, minimizing any risk of electric shock.

Comment: The major concern for safety is no isolation - even though the output is only 5V, it’s riding on top of the full mains voltage and presents a shock hazard. This circuit works fine in, say, a LED lightbulb as it is fully enclosed and no external items like switches etc. The other main safety consideration is if something fails, bits of shrapnel may be ejected from the failing device as well as arc flash. I’d suggest wearing protective eyewear. This also applies to other high energy circuits regardless of the voltage.

Comment: @M-125 issuing warnings is never enough when there are potential hazards. Take as an example the *breadboard*, which is quite **improbably** rated for the 230 Vrms (and more) isolation voltage needed. Then you can witness it hasn't caught fire, and I'm reasonably confident it didn't. However, for a general wide audience, it's always a good idea to write in bold what can go wrong.